# Beamerposter problem: cannot find Runaway argument

Tags: sharelatex, beamerposter

I am trying to learn how to use beamerposter on share latex. I created a share latex file and I copied the contents of http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/~jiarong/poster/icml12-inferning/styles/beamerthemeconfposter.sty into a file, beamerthemeconfposter.sty. I then produced the code at the bottom of this question in the main tex file, but the following error came up:

```
 Runaway argument? main.tec, line 29
 { \end {minipage} \end {center} \end {beamercolorbox} \end {beamercol\ETC. 
 !File ended while scanning use of \beamer@sbtexec. 
 <inserted text>      
          \par 
 I.29 \usetheme{confposter} 
 I suspect you have forgotten a '}', causing me to read past where you              
 wanted me to stop.
```

Here is the code I put in my main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} 

\usetheme{confposter}
\usepackage{exscale} 
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=green,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} 
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10} 

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} 
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} 
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} 
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Oh well} 

\author{Oh well} 

\institute{Oh well} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Oh well.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for having a look at your old questions! I just tested your code and it compiles fine for me. Can you double check that you copy/pasted the complete content of `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`?

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx} ` with beamer.

Comment: That works :) This is from the example produced by Nathaniel Johnston. Why does he include `\usepackage{graphics}`?

Comment: Probably he includes it because he does not know that beamer already loads it? There are also some other strange things with this template, like the way the page size is changed ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as copy/paste problem